# Eliminate a color channel when rendering an object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Am wondering how to eliminate the red channel when rendering some objects in OpenGL.

I can do this easily using a fragment shader but unfortunately I can't use shaders for this particular project.

```
Disable the red channel
DrawOject();
Enable the red channel
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control which channels are written to the framebuffer by using [`glColorMask`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorMask.xml). In your case:

```
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
```